# Iterate through list and check if I am at end of list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list of strings:

```
animals = ["cat meow ", "dog bark"]
```

And I want to check if each string contains the word `"cow"` which obviously does not exist in my above list. I am trying to write an if else statement that checks if I am at the end of the list and if cow is not found print `"not found "`.

The code below prints not found for every element that does not contain the string but I want to print "not found" just once when I iterate my whole list at the end of it but I do not know the correct syntax.

```
animals = ['dog bark' , 'cat meow ']
for pet in animals:
  if 'cow' in pet:
    print('found')
  else:
    print('not  found')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that the not found print will be printed once by

```
animals = ['dog bark' , 'cat meow ']
for i, pet in enumerate(animals):
  if 'cow' in pet:
    print('found')
    break
  elif i+1 == len(animals):
    print('not  found')
```

Or in one line

```
print("found" if [i for i in animals if "cow" in i] else "not  found")
```

This code will print found and exit the loop if there is a cow in one of the else it will check in the last item of it the cow not in the item then it will print 'not  found'.

Answer (score 6):

This seems like a good use case for Python's [any()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function, which returns `True` if any of the items in an iterable are true.

```
animals = ['dog bark' , 'cat meow ']
has_cow = any('cow' in a for a in animals)
print('found' if has_cow else 'not found')
```

But, if you're super eager to use a `for` loop, you could either use a flag variable to track whether you found the item inside the loop or take advantage of Python's truly strange [for-else](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) construct (the else clause executes if the loop was not broken out of). In over a dozen years of Python programming, I have **never** used `for-else`, so it's really just a language curiosity, and I strongly discourage it. But it does work for this specific problem!

```
for a in animals:
    if 'cow' in a:
        print('found')
        break
else:                      # WTF!?!  Don't do this, folks.
    print('not found')
```

Comment: I like the for-else thing in python. I think it is useful in cases like this one.

Comment: @TheLibrarian You might like it, but you are truly outnumbered -- which is fine, to each his/her own. Working Python programmers have not embraced the `for-else` construct.

Answer (score 5):

```
animals = ['dog bark' , 'cat meow ']

print('found' if any('cow' in pet for pet in animals) else 'not found')
```

It works with variables too;

```
result = 'found' if any('cow' in pet for pet in animals) else 'not found'
```

Answer (score 1):

The flag comes in handy at such situations

```
flag = False
animals = ['dog bark' , 'cat meow']
for pet in animals:
  if 'cow' in pet:
      print("Found")
      flag = True

if flag == False:
    print("Not found")
```

It will print `"Not Found"`

For `animals = ['dog bark', 'cat meow', "cow moo"]`, it will print `"Found"`.

Answer (score 1):

Most programming languages allow the use of **else** statements with **if** conditional statements *only*. However in Python, the **else** statement can also be used with **for** loops, of which most of us are unfamiliar. Generally the *for/else* is used to run a loop when we search for an item. Eg:

```
lis=[1,2,3]
for i in lis:
    if i==1:
        print("1 found in list.")
        break
else:
    print("1 is not in list.")
```

This code will print: `1 found in list.`
When the loop runs, *i* takes values in the list, and the *if* statement will check the provided conditions, if the condition is true, the print statement will be executed. After that, the **break** statement is excecuted which *breaks* the flow of control in the code. **Break** statement in Python is used to bring control out of the loop, when some condition is triggered.

Thus the code in the question can correctly be written as:

```
animals=["dog bark","cat meow"]
for pet in animals:
    if 'cow' in pet:
        print("Found")
        break'
else:
    print("not found")
```

This will print the desired result!

Hope it helps!